# RxJS handling closure variables

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive

My scenario is following:
- Reach to database for some object
- After obtaining base object grab it's additional data
- Merge additional data to base object

I wish to write it in pure functional manner (i.e. with no side effects) but so far I'm unable to achieve it:

```
getMeterPointWithMeterDatabyId(id: number, allowEmpty: boolean = false): Observable<MergeObject> {
    const params = this.getEmptyParams();
    let mp: MergeObject; // This is my enclosed objects I refer to

    return this.masterService.getMasterById(params)
    .concatMap<MergeObject, MergeData[]>((master: MergeObject) => {
      mp = master; // This is side effect generation
      return this.meterService.getMasterData(params);
    })
    .concatMap<MasterData[], MergeObject>((md: MasterData[]) => {
      mp.data = md.slice(); // Even more side effects
      return Observable.of(mp); // Final result generated form impure result
    });
```

I think I have a ggo understanding of how Rx works when there is no cycle dependency between objects (i.e. my call chain produced A -> B -> C) but I'm loosing my confidence when I need to step back at one processing step to grab some previous data (i.e. A -> B -> A , where A finally contains B)

EDIT: As far a si know, `zip` operator is doing the trick, but I'd like to know, is it possible to achieve such manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually need the base object to query the details (i.e., the requests must happen consecutively), you can do

```js
this.service.getMaster(id)
  .switchMap(master => this.service.getDetails(master)
    // .catch(…) <-- if you want to continue even if fetching the details fails
    .map(details => merge(master, details))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

The trick is to simply nest the `map` inside the `switchMap`, that way `master` stays in scope without having to jump through hoops.

If the details request is actually independent, you can fire both in parallel using

```js
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.service.getMaster(id),
  this.service.getDetails(id)
    // .catch(…) <-- if you want to continue even if fetching the details fails
)
  .map(([master, details) => merge(master, details))
  .subscribe();
```

---

The technique of delinearizing an operator chain, that is transforming

```js
source$
  .switchMap(data1 => transformationA(data1))
  // From here on out, you only see data1
  .switchMap(data2 => transformationB(data2))
  // From here on out, you only see data2
  .subscribe(data3 => …);
```

into

```js
source$
  .switchMap(data1 => transformationA(data1)
    .switchMap(data2 => transformationB(data2)
    // You can see both data1 and data2 here!
  )
  .subscribe(data3 => …);
```

is useful quite often in order to keep data from multiple steps in scope, e.g. to combine them. It's definitely something to always keep in mind: you can also nest.

Comment: I see your point, but one question: is usage of `switchMap` crucial? Or in fact top-level operator can be any-kind (`concatMap`, `mergeMap` e.c.t) ? Beside that it's clever to start inner-level processing of obtained data. I'll use it in project, thanks!

Comment: For HTTP requests you only fire once there's no notable difference between switchMap and mergeMap. I tend to prefer switchMap because in most scenarios where some trigger is mapped to a request its behavior is what you want (that is, unsubscribing from the inner observable instead of merging all of them together).